# Use combn within a function for nonlinear regression with nlsLM

Tags: r, function, combinations, non-linear-regression, nls

Given is a few rows of a dataframe `DATA`:

```
> dput(DATA[c(1,7,20,25,26,53,89),])
structure(list(Lanes = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), N_b = c(5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5), A = c(-12, -12, -15, -9, -9, -15, -9), x.sqr = 
c(1440, 1440, 2250, 810, 810, 2250, 810), e_1 = c(21.8, 21.8, 
29, 14.6, 14.6, 29, 14.6), e_2 = c(9.8, 9.8, 17, 2.6, 2.6, 17, 
2.6), e_3 = c(-2.2, -2.2, 5, -9.4, -9.4, 5, -9.4), e_4 = 
c(-14.2, -14.2, -7, 0, 0, -7, 0), e_5 = c(0, 0, -19, 0, 0, -19, 0), 
S = c(12, 12, 15, 9, 9, 15, 9), CSi = c(0.59189685884369, 
0.574916237257971, 0.644253184434141, 0.474070747691647, 
0.492033722080107, 0.644904371480046, 0.49900365977452), 
m = c(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85)), row.names = c(1L, 
7L, 20L, 25L, 26L, 53L, 89L), class = "data.frame")
```

I write the function below to use for nonlinear regression with `nlsLM`:

```
library(minpack.lm)

Prposed <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)
  CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (A * combn(e,Lanes,sum) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a))
  return(CSi)
}

nlsLM <- nlsLM(CSi ~ Prposed(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a,b), 
             data = DATA, 
             start = c(a = 0.01, b = 0.01))

summary(nlsLM)
```

I keep getting an error and it is coming from how I am defining the columns `e_1, e_2, etc..` with the `combn` function.

**UPDATE**

I found another question: [Error when running nlsLM but works for nls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005974/error-when-running-nlslm-but-works-for-nls)
which uses a for loop in the original function, and that seems to work fine with the `nls2` function from `library(nls2)`. I was wondering if I could get rid of the `combn` term altogether by going to a for loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an actual answer since it generates a new error after fixing the `combn` error but this might give you some direction.

I think you are trying to run `nlsLM` function for each row in `DATA`. You need to pass each row separately in `Prposed` function. Also note that `a` and `b` are required in the function to perform calculation so they need to be passed as an argument of the function and I think passing them using `start` in `nlsLM` would not work.

So change your function to :

```
library(minpack.lm)

Prposed <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a, b) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)
  CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (A * combn(e,Lanes,sum) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a))
  return(CSi)
}
```

Now let's run this for first row of `DATA` :

```
x <- DATA[1, ]
Prposed(x[[2]], x[[1]], x[[12]], x[[3]], x[[4]], x[[5]], x[[6]], x[[7]], x[[8]],
        x[[9]],x[[10]],a = 0.01, b = 0.01)

#[1] 0.5078651 0.5087365 0.5077053 0.5096079 0.5085767 0.5094481 0.5104793 
#    0.5094481 0.5103195 0.5111909
```

I don't know the theory so I don't know if these numbers make sense/are correct. However, when you plug this in `nlsLM` function it gives an error.

```
nlsLM(CSi~Prposed(x[[2]],x[[1]],x[[12]], x[[3]],x[[4]],x[[5]],x[[6]],x[[7]],
    x[[8]], x[[9]],x[[10]],a = 0.01, b = 0.01),data = DATA)
```

> Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall = as.list(match.call(func,  :
> no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects

Is this because `nlsLM` expects a `formula` object but what we are passing to it is values? I am not sure.

---

Once you get the above step working you can plug this in an `apply` and run it as :

```
apply(DATA, 1, function(x) {
  nlsLM(CSi~Prposed(x[[2]],x[[1]],x[[12]], x[[3]],x[[4]],x[[5]],x[[6]],x[[7]],
    x[[8]], x[[9]],x[[10]],a = 0.01, b = 0.01), data = DATA)
})
```

It works and generates numbers without `nlsLM` function :

```
apply(DATA, 1, function(x) {
  Prposed(x[[2]],x[[1]],x[[12]], x[[3]],x[[4]],x[[5]],x[[6]],x[[7]],x[[8]], 
         x[[9]],x[[10]],a = 0.01, b = 0.01) 
})

#              1         7        20        25        26        53        89
# [1,] 0.5078651 0.5078651 0.5070307 0.5092470 0.5092470 0.5070307 0.5092470
# [2,] 0.5087365 0.5087365 0.5077293 0.5083395 0.5083395 0.5077293 0.5083395
# [3,] 0.5077053 0.5077053 0.5084280 0.5083395 0.5083395 0.5084280 0.5083395
# [4,] 0.5096079 0.5096079 0.5084280 0.5094980 0.5094980 0.5084280 0.5094980
# [5,] 0.5085767 0.5085767 0.5091267 0.5094980 0.5094980 0.5091267 0.5094980
# [6,] 0.5094481 0.5094481 0.5098253 0.5085905 0.5085905 0.5098253 0.5085905
# [7,] 0.5104793 0.5104793 0.5091267 0.5106565 0.5106565 0.5091267 0.5106565
# [8,] 0.5094481 0.5094481 0.5098253 0.5106565 0.5106565 0.5098253 0.5106565
# [9,] 0.5103195 0.5103195 0.5105240 0.5097490 0.5097490 0.5105240 0.5097490
#[10,] 0.5111909 0.5111909 0.5112227 0.5109075 0.5109075 0.5112227 0.5109075
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but I am still getting the same error. How did you update the function `Proposed` it looks the same as the original post.

Comment: I added an argument `b` to it. Try to run this for one row first. `x <- DATA[1, ]` and then `Prposed(x[[2]], x[[1]], x[[12]], x[[3]], x[[4]], x[[5]], x[[6]], x[[7]], x[[8]],x[[9]],x[[10]],a = 0.01, b = 0.01)` does it give you the output as in my post?

Comment: Thank you so much. How I return the max value of the output? i tried `max(combn(e,Lanes,sum)` and `return(max(CSi))`

Comment: Both should work.  `max(combn(e,Lanes,sum))` and with `return` as well. Did you run the function again for changes to reflect?

Comment: Yes, Thank you got it fixed! Apparently the error for no 'getInitial' method is because of missing the start term in the nlsLM function. if I just add a `, start=c(a=0.01, b=0.01)` after defining `data = DATA`, then the error changes to Error in qr(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")) : 
  dims [product 2] do not match the length of object [198]

Comment: Does it work for you for one row? When I try `nlsLM(CSi~Prposed(x[[2]],x[[1]],x[[12]], x[[3]],x[[4]],x[[5]],x[[6]],x[[7]], x[[8]], x[[9]],x[[10]],a = 0.01, b = 0.01),data = DATA, start=c(a=0.01, b=0.01))` it returns  `Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates`

Comment: No I still get the same error. I can only get it to work if I ignore the `combn` term all together and run `nls(CSi~Prposed(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,S,a,b),  data = DATA, start=c(a=0.01,b=0.5))`. Using this format with `combn` is not possible cause I back to the initial problem of getting `Error in combn(e, Lanes, sum) : length(m) == 1L is not TRUE`

Comment: What is `N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,S,a,b` in this case?

Comment: The way nls functions are usually written, the variables should be listed the same way as the original function so if I had `Prposed <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a, b) { e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5) CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (A * combn(e,Lanes,sum) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a)) return(CSi)}` then the nls function should also be defined as `nls(CSi~Prposed(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,S,a,b),  data = DATA, start=c(a=0.01,b=0.5))`

Answer (score 1):

I had to define the by row operation within the original function

```
Proposed <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a,b) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)
  CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (max(A * combn(seq_along(e), Lanes, FUN = function(i) rowSums(e[i]))) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a))
  return(CSi)
}

nlsLM <- nlsLM(CSi ~ Proposed(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a,b), 
             data = DATA, 
             start = c(a = 0.01, b = 0.01))

summary(nlsLM)
```